# Error: Could not find or load main class is seen even after giving the classpath

Tags: java, classpath, command-prompt

i am trying to execute a java program from command prompt.
On executing the below command the error - Error: Could not find or load main class is seen. The command includes the path to jar files and also path to out folder where class files are present. The same program is working fine in Intellij though.

```
[root@abc TagPackage]# java -cp "/home/admin/TagAPI/out/production   /TagAPI/TagPackage/*":"/home/admin/TagAPI/lib/*"  Test3
```

Error: Could not find or load main class Test3

The structure of my program is as below :

TagAPI> src> (Package)TagPackage> Test3.java

Any suggestion will be helpful, Thanks!!

Comment: Do you *really* have spaces in your directory name, or did you mean `"/home/admin/TagAPI/out/production/TagAPI/TagPackage/*"`? I'd also try listing the jar files explicitly. Oh, and if you mean that the package name is `TagPackage`, you'd need `java .... TagPackage.Test3` as that's the full name of the class.

Comment: i tried with the  TagPackage.Test3, getting the same error msg

Comment: So did you read the rest of my comment as well? There were three suggestions there...